# Creating Dynamic Select Query in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have researched this topic and have decided just to ask here since I can't seem to find anything. I'll explain below:

Context: Flask Application with a form the client fills out and posts to the server. The form inputs are used to create a query and return data.

I am using SQLalchemy currently to construct the query from scratch. At this point, I have successfully connected to my existing Redshift database and can query properly but I cannot figure out how to dynamically construct a simple `Select x, y, z` statement based on the user's form inputs.

The main problem being that `Query()` can't take in a python list of columns. It seems you must specify each column like `table.c.column1` which doesn't work well with a dynamic query since I don't know what columns I want until the user submits the form.

My 2 ideas so far:

1. Loop through all column names and use `Query.add_columns(table.c['colname'])`
2. Use `select([col1, col2, ...])` instead of `Query()`
3. Use `load_columns()` to load only specific columns in a table to query. Unfortunately seems to only work with model objects and not reflected tables unless I am mistaken

Both of these seem backwards to me as they do not really accomplish my goal effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is quite flexible, so both 1 and 2 get the job done. If you've no need for ORM functionality, then perhaps #2 is more natural. If the user were to pass a list of column names such as

```
columns = request.args.getlist('columns')
```

you could then create your `select()` quite easily with a bunch of [`column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) constructs:

```
stmt = select([column(c) for c in columns]).\
    select_from(some_table)
```

or if you have the table at hand, like you hint in the question:

```
stmt = select([table.c[c] for c in columns])
```

and then all that is left is to execute your statement:

```
results = db.session.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```

Comment: Okay, I might just go with using `select()` then. I was just wondering if there was a better way to go about it  using `Query()` since that is what seems to be the preferred method of querying by the writers of sqlalchemy. I kind of assumed something would be available to cover this use case.

Comment: You could actually use the same method with `Query` as well, with some slight modifications. A `Query` expects entities to select as positional arguments, where `select()` takes a list.

Comment: The `Session.query()` method expects pos. args., to be exact. The `Query` constructor also takes a sequence of entities as first argument, but usually the method on a session is used.

Comment: can you elaborate on how to do this using `query()`? Since I can't pass in the entities as args to query() as a list, how else would I pass them in? Reason being, I need to pass in X number of columns and not a set amount.

Comment: You can unpack an iterable as positional arguments to a function with the asterisk: `db.session.query(*[table.c[c] for c in columns])` for example.

Comment: The third suggestion worked for me. Thank you,, @IljaEverilä