# Extract raw sql from SqlAlchemy with replaced parameters

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Given a sql query such as

```
query = """
select some_col from tbl where some_col > :value
"""
```

I'm executing this with sqlalchemy using

```
connection.execute(sa.text(query), {'value' : 5})
```

Though this does what's expected, I would like to be able to get the raw sql, with replaced parameters. Meaning I would like a way to be able to get

```
select some_column from tbl where some_column > 5
```

I've tried to echo the sql using:

```
    engine = sa.create_engine(
        '<CONNECTION STRING>',
        echo=True,
    )
```

But this didn't replace the parameters.

If there's not a way to do this in sqlalchemy, but is a way using something like psycopg2 (as long as the syntax `:value` doesn't change) then that would be of interest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a raw, compiled SQL query from a SQLAlchemy expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617291/how-do-i-get-a-raw-compiled-sql-query-from-a-sqlalchemy-expression)

Comment: @IanWilson thanks - I'm not sure how I would apply that answer to my question. From the context lower down on the page it seems that `q` is different to the raw string that I have in my example.

Comment: You have to understand that for a query with parametriesed *columns* you'll need a *dynamic SQL*. Search for "SqlAlchemy dynamic SQL" e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46598276/4808122)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber thanks - sorry but I don't understand why this is dynamic in the sense of what you've linked. I know exactly what I want, there's nothing here which is variable or dynamic - it's just parameterised.

Comment: You will never get those two queries `select col1 from T` and `select col2 from T` to work with a parameter `'col1'`  and `'col2'`.  You can't pass *table* or *column* names in a way as you pass a *value* in `where col = :id` - you **need a dynamic SQL** @baxx

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Sorry to cause confusion there I wasn't aware - I have updated the post to be clearer in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy documentation for [Rendering Bound Parameters Inline](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/sqlexpressions.html#rendering-bound-parameters-inline) explains how we can use `literal_binds`:

```py
query = "select some_col from tbl where some_col > :value"
print(
    sa.text(query)
    .bindparams(value=5)
    .compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
)
# select some_col from tbl where some_col > 5
```